# Are the problems PRIMES, FACTORING known to be P-hard?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, lower-bounds, factoring, primes, p-hardness

Let [PRIMES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test) (a.k.a. *primality testing*) be the problem:

> Given a natural number $n$, is $n$ a prime number?

Let [FACTORING](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization) be the problem:

> Given natural numbers $n$, $m$ with $1 \leq m \leq n$, does $n$ have a factor $d$ with $1 < d < m$?

Is it known whether PRIMES is P-hard? How about FACTORING? 
What are the best known lowerbounds for these problems?

Comment: No, IIRC it is open if Primes is P-hard. I think the same is true about FACTORING.

Comment: I guess an alternate question might be: are there any consequences for PRIMES or FACTORING being P-hard ?

Comment: @Suresh: that is a nice question.  Could you post it separately?

Comment: Actually it's already been asked for factoring: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/5096/consequences-of-factoring-being-in-p

Comment: @András I would suggested that the consequences be assumed (or explicitly added) as part of this question. Otherwise the question starts to border on wikipedia-able.

Comment: @Artem, I agree with András, a question about consequences of P-hardness of Primes would be interesting. I also edited the question by adding a question about the best known lowerbounds.

Comment: @Suresh, that seems to be about the consequences of upperbound for FACTORING (being in P), not a lowerbound for it (being P-hard).

Comment: @Kaveh Hmm. good point. although Peter Shor appears to have answered the question for FACTORING

Comment: What type of reduction are we considering?

Answer (score 40):

PRIMES is known to be hard for $\mathsf{TC^0}$.  See my paper with Saks and Shparlinski, "[A Lower Bound for Primality](http://ftp.cs.rutgers.edu/pub/allender/primes.pdf)" in JCSS 62 (2001).  No improvement on that front since then.

Comment: do you know if this hardness result also holds if we only want some random $\frac1 n$ of all $n$-bit integers to be factored? After all this could still be in $ACC^0$ right?

Answer (score 31):

Factoring can be achieved by using a polylog $n$ depth quantum circuit, and ZPP pre- and post-processing; [see this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0006004). If it were P-hard, any algorithm in P could be done with polylog $n$ depth quantum circuit and the same pre- and post-processing steps. I believe these steps are modular exponentiation and continued fractions, which to me seem unlikely to be powerful enough to solve P-complete problems, even with the addition of a polylog $n$ depth quantum circuit.