# A quantum algorithm for GCD

Tags: approximation-algorithms, quantum-computing

Does anyone know of a direct quantum algorithm for computing GCD, - There could be quantum gates for addition subtraction constructed explicitly, using CNOT, etc. - the construction can be done in some poly(n) of input, (this is just a guess), but is there any algorithm, scheme for computing GCD, using quantum algorithms, gauss sums, QFT, quantum approximation, anything(!!) thanks,

Comment: related? http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/16773/is-there-a-quantum-nc-algorithm-for-computing-gcd

Comment: @Tom The way you phrased the question, it doesn't make much sense to me. What is the goal, improving the complexity? I agree with Logan that you should revise it and maybe ask for a specific approach, once you have fixed the goal you want to obtain.

Answer (score 1):

A search for "Quantum GCD" yields a 2013 paper by Saeedi and Markov titled ["Quantum Circuits for GCD Computation with O(n \log n) Depth and O(n) Ancillae"](http://arxiv.org/abs/1304.7516). It's not mentioned in the title, but the size of the circuit used in their algorithm $O(n^2)$.

Comment: I was wondering if there was an approach using Gaussian sums(like van dam seroussi), wherein we get an Eulers coefficient(tells us number of relative primes relative to N), and then start from there to get the gcd!

Comment: You should probably revise your question to make that more clear. I read your question as, "Is there a Quantum Algorithm for GCD?"